# How to run cucumber separately from rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Hi I am working on ROR project with rails 5 and ruby 2.5.1. I have written test cases in cucumber. When i run cucumber it runs locally i.e it gives the output based on local code but i want to test the remote API. How can i test the remote API without depending on local rails code?. I tried to mention the remote URL as follows:

```
When(/^I send a GET request to receipt details$/) do
  @url = "http://example.com/api/receipts"
end

Then(/^the json response should have main receipt status complete$/) do
  header 'login-token', @login_token
  header 'user-id', @user_id
  response = get @url
  response_body = JSON response.body
  @id = response_body['data']['id']
  expect(response_body['data']['attributes']['status']).to eq('complete')
end
```

But still it checks for the local routes '/api/receipts'. It doesn't call the URL.
Please help me Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to test the remote api. Is it your api, or is it an external service you are using. What would you do if the remote api failed?

Comment: yeah its my api. i want to test my staging env. how can i set the base_url?

Comment: run the cukes on your staging environment, or run your api locally, or write unit tests.